# Autosys Box Job is turning to Success when box job has scheduled time for cmd Jobs [start_mins: 3,18,33,48 ] run_window: "12:20-14:30" on box

Tags: autosys

I have one Autosys Job set-up scenario like below, to achieve the aim start/stop multiple servers level deployed application  jobs on single click at environment level as well as server level

example:

Box 1 (Environment level like UAT ) >>  Box2 (Server level like Host1 ) >> CMD1 (Application 1 deployed on Host1)  & CMD2 (Application 1 deployed on Host1)  jobs

BOX1 Job I have created at environment level Like UAT environment

This UAT environment has 4 servers which have multiple cmd jobs

So each server I am treating as Box2 and deployed applications as cmd Jobs

**BOX Job 1:**

```
insert_job: **150_OneTouch_START_UAT**    job_type: box

description: UAT START BOX

owner: RG76WC

alarm_if_fail: n

alarm_if_terminated: n

date_conditions: y

run_window: "12:20-14:30"

days_of_week: su,mo,tu,we,th,fr,sa

start_times: "12:21"

send_notification: n
```

BOX Job2:

```
insert_job: **150_OneTouch_START_U1_Server**    job_type: box

description: U1 Server App box

owner: RG76WC

box_name: **150_OneTouch_START_UAT   **

alarm_if_fail: n

alarm_if_terminated: n

run_window: "12:21-14:29"

date_conditions: y

days_of_week: su,mo,tu,we,th,fr,sa

start_times: "12:22"

send_notification: n
```

CMD Job1  (This job supposed to run in every hours 4 times as mentioned here in config - start_mins: 3,18,33,48)

```
insert_job: 150_OneTouch_START_U1_Server_App_CDSEJ    job_type: cmd

machine: sd-4567-fghj.nam.nsroot.net

owner: RG76WC

box_name: **150_OneTouch_START_U1_Server  **  

permission: me,mx,ge,gx,we,wx

alarm_if_fail: y

alarm_if_terminated: y

date_conditions: y

days_of_week: su,mo,tu,we,th,fr,sa

start_mins: 3,18,33,48

send_notification: n

std_out_file: >> /var/tmp/$AUTO_JOB_NAME.out

std_err_file: >> /var/tmp/$AUTO_JOB_NAME.err

command: /home/RG76WC/CDS2IodEtl/cds2config/startETL.sh
```

CMD Job2

```
insert_job: 150424_OneTouch_START_U1_Server_App_MQDataFeed    job_type: cmd

machine: sd-4567-fghj.nam.nsroot.net

owner: RG76WC

box_name: **150_OneTouch_START_U1_Server**    

permission: me,mx,ge,gx,we,wx

alarm_if_fail: y

alarm_if_terminated: y

date_conditions: y

days_of_week: su,mo,tu,we,th,fr

start_times: "12:25"

send_notification: n

std_out_file: >> /var/tmp/$AUTO_JOB_NAME.out

std_err_file: >> /var/tmp/$AUTO_JOB_NAME.err

command: /home/RG76WC/SourceMQDataApp/startSourceMQDataApp.sh
```

In the mentioned set-up , We want box to keep running until define run_window: "12:20-14:30" duration so that box should remain in running status during this time, and underlying cmd job1  should keep running for define regulars interval [start_mins: 3,18,33,48 ] which is 4 times in an hour

But with this set-up we are observing once cmd job1 and cmd job 2 getting executed at defined start_mins and turning to successful status for first time attempt, box 2 and box 1 job is also getting turn to success due to which we are not able to see cmd 1 job is running for next interval with-in defined run_window: "12:20-14:30" again.

How can I fulfill this business requirement? with this set-up we are turning underlying cmd job start to control at single click from both level environment and server level.